# Edit pdf document tool? Form will not render without Adobe

Tags: pdf

I would like to download the pdf application form on [this](https://www.gov.uk/apply-for-a-licence/house-in-multiple-occupation-licence-2/edinburgh/renew-1) page.

When I download and open with document viewer app, I get this message when I open the doc:
[image]

I went to the Ubuntu software center and typed 'pdf' in the search box. There are several results:
[image]

Before I try some trial and error with those apps, is there an app for Ubuntu (18.04) that anyone knows of that could render this document?

Comment: The document probably includes some "feature" that is proprietary to Adobe software.  I've seen this before with some signature fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, that is super scummy of your council to force citizens into using Adobe.

You can try using suggestions provided [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/752425/how-to-open-a-pdf-form-file-that-says-please-wait)

Alternatively, you can install an older version of adbobe reader. I was able to install it with these 3 simple steps :
`sudo apt install gdebi-core libxml2:i386 libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 gtk2-engines-murrine:i386 libatk-adaptor:i386`

`wget ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/unix/9.x/9.5.5/enu/AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb`

`sudo dpkg -i  AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb`

For some wierd reason the installation puts the executables under `/opt/Adobe/Reader9/bin`  and not in the common locations like `/usr/bin` `/usr/local/bin`. So, you will need to run `acroread` from `/opt/Adobe/Reader9/bin` .

Comment: This does indeed work, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Try [Foxit Reader](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf-reader/), there is a Linux version available. I have seen Foxit Reader (although on Windows) properly display files which even Adobe Reader can't handle correctly... :)

Answer (score 0):

MuPDF reads those council PDF's none of the others do, I tried.

Comment: Actually it does!!!,  Short and to the point. But you can go and answer all the questions, I am out. No wonder people say the community is toxic. It is people like you who make it so. I just wanted to help teh poor guy with his issue that I struggled with before. Then you mark it as NOT providing the answer when it CLEARLY does. . But I am done.